# VBA functions use in ArcGIS Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-9.3, excel

Would this be ok to use them for the field calculator in ArcGIS 9.3  ? See here [MS Excel VBA Functions](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_vba_alpha.php)

Or should I fix them in MS Excel and save as a file and then use the join with the shapefile or file geodatabase. Will this work ? Will ArcGIS read it in table ?

Please advice as I am looking for information on how to use field calculator.

Thanks

Comment: Some of those functions are built-in to VBA, some are specific to Excel. For examples of VBA functions available in the field calculator see: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/31807

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to use it to force the decimals remove and replace with the comma. Here I have a column with acres like this 506320.0750 and I want this (506,320) to display permanmently ?

Comment: Please ask a separate question for this.

Comment: I posted in a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [technical document](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/31807) describing some of the basic VBA calculator functions, with links to some short walk-throughs. And here is some [narrative](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Making_field_calculations) (with examples) on using the Field Calculator and VBA.

Remember that using VBA in the field calculator is only valid for 9.3.1 and not 10 (which uses python and VBScript).

Answer (score 1):

You can open field calculator and use a function like...
ltrim [my_field]
Then in field calculator you will see a save button.
This will save a file that can be reloaded in caclulator.
You can view this file in notepad (or other text editor).
As blah238 said the knowledgebase article will help show what can and can't be used.

NOTE: You will only be able to use field calculator on the left side of your join (unless you create a dbf file with an oid and join that).
[Esri join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002p000000.htm)
[Calculations](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Fundamentals_of_field_calculations/005s00000025000000/)
[Examples](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/005s0000002m000000/)